# play a mp4 file and then switch to a view controller, file plays fine but cannot figure out the code to switch to another view

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import AVKit

class Class1: AVPlayerViewController, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func playVideo() {

        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("output_aV7EL0", ofType: "mp4") {
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
            player?.play()
        }
        else {
            print("Oops, something wrong when playing video.mp4")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        playVideo()
    }

    func AVPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer!, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if player.playing {
            player.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

I Have gotten the mp4 file to play but i need to switch to a different view once the video has finished playing, How would I go about that? Any tips would be appreciated.

func playVideo() {

```
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("output_aV7EL0", ofType: "mp4") {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        player?.play()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.presentViewController(viewcontrollerToPresent: GameViewController1, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the question has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "switching" to a different view? Can you be more specific?

If you want to close the page do this:

1. If it's in a navigation controller:

   ```
   self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
   ```
2. If it's presented:

   ```
   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   ```

If you want to present another view controller:

1. If it's in a navigation controller:

   ```
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourViewController, animated: true)
   ```
2. If you want to modally present it:

   ```
   self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

Comment: It is a view controller and i want it to close the view and switch to a different view

Comment: then your solution is in the answer I provided, close the presented view controller using the 2 code and in the parent view controller (the one that originally presented your player view controller), present another view controller when the player view controller gets dismissed.

Comment: Thank you Peyman, that code works fine now but I'm i get the error that 'Cannot convert value of type 'GameViewController1.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'. But my GameViewController1 is a UIViewController so I'm quite confused

Comment: My intuition is that you're passing the type of GameViewController not an instance of it. show the line of code you're getting this error at